# How to declare a System.Linq.IQueryable variable with a complex query

Tags: linq

I have a working query as below:

```
var result = from sch in schemeDashboard
             join exp in Expenditure on sch.schemeId equals exp.SchemeCode
             into SchExpGroup
             where sch.SectorDepartmentId == selectedDepartmentId &&
                   sch.YearCode == StateManager.CurrentYear
             orderby sch.ADPId
             select new
             {
                ProjectName = sch.schemeName,
                ADPNo = sch.ADPId,
                Allocation = sch.CurrentAllocation,
                Expenditures = from expend in SchExpGroup
                               where expend.YearCode == StateManager.CurrentYear && 
                                     expend.DepartmentId == selectedDepartmentId &&
                                     InvStatus.Contains(expend.Status)
                             orderby expend.ADPId
                             group expend by expend.InvoiceId
              };
```

Now I need to declare "result" as: `System.Linq.IQueryable<...>  result = null;` so that I can write the query in various If-else blocks with minor modification. (projectName is string, ADPNo is int, Allocation is decimal).

I have tried as follow:

```
System.Linq.IQueryable<string, int, decimal, 
         System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Expenditure>>> result = null;
```

But this is giving error as: `The non-generic type 'IQueryable' cannot be used with typed arguments.`
Can anyone point me in right direction? thanx.

Comment: You have a queryable of an anonymous type here so you can't explicitly specify your variable. But what is wrong with using `var` anyway? There's nothing stopping you from saying something like `result = result.Where(x => x.Id == 5);`

Comment: There is even the problem of the join that creates another anonymous type

Comment: @DavidG  thanks. your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1):

The most generical class of C# is the class object. So you can declare your list with the Object type.

```
IQueryable <object> result = null;
```

Well I hope it works for you as it worked for me.